# How to insert and update records in a database behind a cms using c# and directus api?

Tags: c#, jwt, directus

I want to insert and update a record in a cms using c# and the directus api. I don't know how to do this.
I need also use a JWT token to insert and update the records in the cms. Can you help me?

I have described that i need to know how to update and insert records in a database behind a cms using c# and the directus api. I expect code pieces where i can see how to make post and update calls using c#, directus api and jwt token.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can just use HttpClient's Get , Post and Patch methods to do this ,
bellow you can find a draft class (with static members) with read/insert/update (delete is not yet implemented , nor is login ...)

For Authentication you should generate a token for a user from directus admin panel , then you pass it as parameter to the Directus class :
(or You can implement login with username and password wich returns a authentication token).

You can use it like this :

```cs
// init once like this
Directus.serverUrl = "http://192.168.1.100:8055";
Directus.accessToken = "<past_your_access_token_here>";


// then you can retrieve data like :
string filter = "filter[status][_eq]=published&filter[field1][_eq]=value1";
var response = await Directus.GetItems("table_name", filter);
var obj = JObject.Parse(response)

/////

var datarow = JObject.FromObject(new { 
   field1 = value1, 
   field2 = value2 
});

// insert
await Directus.InsertItem("table_name",datarow);

// update
await Directus.UpdateItem("table_name", "<id>", datarow));
```

```cs
class Directus
{
    public static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    public static String? serverUrl;
    public static String? accessToken;

    public static void Auth()
    {
        if(httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization == null)
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Directus.accessToken);
        }
    }

    public static Task<string> GetItems(string? table, string? filters)
    {
        return GetAsync("/items/" + table , filters);
    }

    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> InsertItem(string? table, JObject? item)
    {
        return PostAsync("/items/" + table, item);
    }

    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateItem(string? table, string id, JObject? item)
    {
        return PatchAsync("/items/" + table + "/" + id, item);
    }

    private static Task<string> GetAsync(string? action, string? filters)
    {
        Auth();
        return httpClient.GetStringAsync(Directus.serverUrl + action + "?" + filters);
    }

    private static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string? action, JObject? item)
    {
        Auth();
        var content = new StringContent(item.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        Console.WriteLine("PostAsync Action : {0}", action);
        //Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

        return httpClient.PostAsync(Directus.serverUrl + action , content);
    }

    private static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(string? action, JObject? item)
    {
        Auth();
        var content = new StringContent(item.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        Console.WriteLine("PatchAsync Action : {0}", action);
        //Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

        return httpClient.PatchAsync(Directus.serverUrl + action , content);
    }
}
```